# (C, α)/(C,k) summation

Tags: divergent-series

I'm stuck here at a definition in Hardy's "Divergent Series". On page 96 he defines the Cesàro means $(C,k)$ by
*We write*
$A_n^{0} = A_n = a_0 + a_1 + ... + a_n \quad , ..., \quad A_n^k = A_0^{k-1} + A_1^{k-1} + ... + A_n^{k-1}$
*and* $E_n^k$ *for the value of* $A_n^k$ *when* $a_0 = 1$  *and* $a_n = 0$ *for* $n>0$
, i.e. , *when* $A_n = 1$ for all $n$. If
$ C_n^k(A) = \frac{A_n^k}{E_n^k} \to A$
*when* $n\to\infty$, *then we say that* $\sum a_n$ is summable $(C,k)$ *to sum* $A$, *and write* $a_0+a_1+a_2 + ... = A \quad (C,k).$
What I don't really understand here (maybe because of my English) is what happens with $E_n^k$ if $A_n$ is **not** 1 + 0 + 0 + 0  + ... It's written that $(C, k=1)$ is the usual Cesàro summation, that one however, can sum 1-1+1-1+1-1+...
while not having to meet the conditions for the $(C,k)$ summation. What am I overlooking/misunderstanding? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This answer is 1:1 copied from [my answer on mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/a/344274/7710) to prevent loss, if MO closes your question there*

---

The question on $E^k_n$ shows a somehow misleaded intuition here, so I think it would be good to show an example display of the process.

If we assume *the process* of building partial sums, and partial sums of partial sums, and etc, of an initial sequence $A$ as an iterated *operation* ***D*** , then we compare the intermediate results of $D^k$ applied on $A$ with $D^k$ applied to $E$ where $E$ is defined as a constant $E=[1,0,0,...]$

The $k$-times application of operation $D$ on $A$ gives the sequence $A^k$ and on $E$ gives $E^k$ , and then we simply divide the values $A^k$ by $E^k$.
This is somehow a *normalizing* of the operation $D$ .

Here I show the partial results for $A^0=[1,-2,3,-4,5,-6,...]$ up to $k=4$ . We see, that for $k=3$ the values in the comlumn $A/E$ approach visibly the expected value $0.25$ and for $k=4$ it seems to be the same, only with slower convergence. So application of Cesarosum with order $3$ should give the best approximation with least terms involved while the results for $k<3$ are not converging.

$$ \Tiny \begin{array} {rrr|rrr|rrr|rrr|rrr}
 A^0& E^0& A/E & A^1& E^1& A/E & A^2& E^2& A/E & A^3& E^3& A/E & A^4& E^4& A/E & \\ \hline
 1 & 1 & 1.00000 & 1 & 1 & 1.00000 & 1 & 1 & 1.00000 & 1 & 1 & 1.00000 & 1 & 1 & 1.00000 \\ 
 -2 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 1 & -1.00000 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 1 & 3 & 0.333333 & 2 & 4 & 0.500000 \\ 
 3 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 1 & 2.00000 & 2 & 3 & 0.666667 & 3 & 6 & 0.500000 & 5 & 10 & 0.500000 \\ 
 -4 & 0 & 0 & -2 & 1 & -2.00000 & 0 & 4 & 0 & 3 & 10 & 0.300000 & 8 & 20 & 0.400000 \\ 
 5 & 0 & 0 & 3 & 1 & 3.00000 & 3 & 5 & 0.600000 & 6 & 15 & 0.400000 & 14 & 35 & 0.400000 \\ 
 -6 & 0 & 0 & -3 & 1 & -3.00000 & 0 & 6 & 0 & 6 & 21 & 0.285714 & 20 & 56 & 0.357143 \\ 
 7 & 0 & 0 & 4 & 1 & 4.00000 & 4 & 7 & 0.571429 & 10 & 28 & 0.357143 & 30 & 84 & 0.357143 \\ 
 -8 & 0 & 0 & -4 & 1 & -4.00000 & 0 & 8 & 0 & 10 & 36 & 0.277778 & 40 & 120 & 0.333333 \\ 
 9 & 0 & 0 & 5 & 1 & 5.00000 & 5 & 9 & 0.555556 & 15 & 45 & 0.333333 & 55 & 165 & 0.333333 \\ 
 -10 & 0 & 0 & -5 & 1 & -5.00000 & 0 & 10 & 0 & 15 & 55 & 0.272727 & 70 & 220 & 0.318182 \\ 
 11 & 0 & 0 & 6 & 1 & 6.00000 & 6 & 11 & 0.545455 & 21 & 66 & 0.318182 & 91 & 286 & 0.318182 \\ 
 -12 & 0 & 0 & -6 & 1 & -6.00000 & 0 & 12 & 0 & 21 & 78 & 0.269231 & 112 & 364 & 0.307692 \\ 
 13 & 0 & 0 & 7 & 1 & 7.00000 & 7 & 13 & 0.538462 & 28 & 91 & 0.307692 & 140 & 455 & 0.307692 \\ 
 -14 & 0 & 0 & -7 & 1 & -7.00000 & 0 & 14 & 0 & 28 & 105 & 0.266667 & 168 & 560 & 0.300000 \\ 
 15 & 0 & 0 & 8 & 1 & 8.00000 & 8 & 15 & 0.533333 & 36 & 120 & 0.300000 & 204 & 680 & 0.300000 \\ 
 -16 & 0 & 0 & -8 & 1 & -8.00000 & 0 & 16 & 0 & 36 & 136 & 0.264706 & 240 & 816 & 0.294118 \\ 
 17 & 0 & 0 & 9 & 1 & 9.00000 & 9 & 17 & 0.529412 & 45 & 153 & 0.294118 & 285 & 969 & 0.294118 \\ 
 -18 & 0 & 0 & -9 & 1 & -9.00000 & 0 & 18 & 0 & 45 & 171 & 0.263158 & 330 & 1140 & 0.289474 \\ 
 19 & 0 & 0 & 10 & 1 & 10.0000 & 10 & 19 & 0.526316 & 55 & 190 & 0.289474 & 385 & 1330 & 0.289474 \\ 
 -20 & 0 & 0 & -10 & 1 & -10.0000 & 0 & 20 & 0 & 55 & 210 & 0.261905 & 440 & 1540 & 0.285714 \\ 
 21 & 0 & 0 & 11 & 1 & 11.0000 & 11 & 21 & 0.523810 & 66 & 231 & 0.285714 & 506 & 1771 & 0.285714 \\ 
 -22 & 0 & 0 & -11 & 1 & -11.0000 & 0 & 22 & 0 & 66 & 253 & 0.260870 & 572 & 2024 & 0.282609 \\ 
 23 & 0 & 0 & 12 & 1 & 12.0000 & 12 & 23 & 0.521739 & 78 & 276 & 0.282609 & 650 & 2300 & 0.282609 \\ 
 -24 & 0 & 0 & -12 & 1 & -12.0000 & 0 & 24 & 0 & 78 & 300 & 0.260000 & 728 & 2600 & 0.280000 \\ 
 25 & 0 & 0 & 13 & 1 & 13.0000 & 13 & 25 & 0.520000 & 91 & 325 & 0.280000 & 819 & 2925 & 0.280000 \\ 
 -26 & 0 & 0 & -13 & 1 & -13.0000 & 0 & 26 & 0 & 91 & 351 & 0.259259 & 910 & 3276 & 0.277778 \\ 
 27 & 0 & 0 & 14 & 1 & 14.0000 & 14 & 27 & 0.518519 & 105 & 378 & 0.277778 & 1015 & 3654 & 0.277778 \\ 
 -28 & 0 & 0 & -14 & 1 & -14.0000 & 0 & 28 & 0 & 105 & 406 & 0.258621 & 1120 & 4060 & 0.275862 \\ 
 29 & 0 & 0 & 15 & 1 & 15.0000 & 15 & 29 & 0.517241 & 120 & 435 & 0.275862 & 1240 & 4495 & 0.275862 \\ 
 -30 & 0 & 0 & -15 & 1 & -15.0000 & 0 & 30 & 0 & 120 & 465 & 0.258065 & 1360 & 4960 & 0.274194 \\ 
 31 & 0 & 0 & 16 & 1 & 16.0000 & 16 & 31 & 0.516129 & 136 & 496 & 0.274194 & 1496 & 5456 & 0.274194 \\ 
 -32 & 0 & 0 & -16 & 1 & -16.0000 & 0 & 32 & 0 & 136 & 528 & 0.257576 & 1632 & 5984 & 0.272727 \\
 \vdots& \vdots&\vdots & \vdots& \vdots& \vdots & \vdots& \vdots& \vdots & \vdots& \vdots& \vdots &\vdots& \vdots& \vdots & \\ 
 \end{array} $$

Comment: wow thank you so much!! Yeah I was really confused because Hardy used the notation of a series $a_0 + ...$ for both, $A_n^k$ and $E_n^k$. Everything makes sense now.